# What's your favorite mootools widgets and plugin

Tags: plugins, mootools, widget

I'm still new with Mootools. I'm trying to collect informations regarding the good and worth using Mootools plugins out there around the net.

Please list your favourite Mootools widgets and plugins.

One widgets and plugins per post only please so others can vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clientcide libraries](http://www.clientcide.com/js). Very useful stuff (though I only used the FormValidator yet).

Answer (score 1):

meteora mootools widgets http://meteora.astrata.com.mx

Answer (score 0):

[Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/demo/slimbox/) (Lightbox clone, but more responsive UI).

Comment: Mmmh, it doesn't run well with Moo 1.2 doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I used this [Autocompleter](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/) recently, and it's quite simple and do it's job well.